# How do I pass $scope to service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get data to update my expression {{myList}} but it seem like I have the $scope issue in my service, below code doesn't seem to work :

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'getTopicContent', function($scope,getTopicContent){
    getTopicContent.request();

}]);

app.factory('getTopicContent', ['$http', function($http, $scope){

    var query = function() {
        return $http({
            url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/mydata.me/level1/list.php",
            method: "GET"
        }).success(function(data, $scope){
            $scope.myList= data;
        });
    }

    return {
        request : function(){
            return query();
        }

    }
}]);
```

But if I do like this it will work http://pastebin.com/T7rjKYds, which I run the .`success` in the controller instead of within my service.

Comment: change `app.factory('getTopicContent', ['$http','$scope', function($http, $scope)`

Comment: @RandomUser I tried this before it doesn't work, it says Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- getTopicContent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services and factories are independent of the scope. They don't have access to `$scope` through dependency injection to ensure proper separation of concerns.

You have two options, pass the `$scope` to your `getTopicContent.request($scope)` method like this:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'getTopicContent', function($scope,getTopicContent){
    getTopicContent.request($scope);
}]);

app.factory('getTopicContent', ['$http', function($http){

    var query = function($scope) {
        return $http({
            url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/mydata.me/level1/list.php",
            method: "GET"
        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.myList = data;
        });
    }

    return {
        request : function($scope){
            return query($scope);
        }

    }
}]);
```

Or return the promise and add the `success()` handler inside the controller instead:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'getTopicContent', function($scope,getTopicContent){
    getTopicContent.request().success(function(data){
        $scope.myList = data;
    });
}]);


app.factory('getTopicContent', ['$http', function($http){

    var query = function() {
        return $http({
            url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/mydata.me/level1/list.php",
            method: "GET"
        })
    }

    return {
        request : function(){
            return query();
        }

    }
}]);
```

Comment: I think the second option is cleaner, what do u think?

Comment: what if I want to run my service in $state?

Comment: One thing to add to this is that you never pass a scope to a service. It's always the scope that has access to the service, not the other way around. Like @Sly_cardinal said, you are able to pass the scope variable as a parameter to your service and act upon it, but your service won't always have access to a scope.